# passphrase protecting a ca private key not working using openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa

I'm trying to passphrase protect a ca private rsa key.

I'm using the command:

```
openssl genrsa -out ./rootca/private/cakey.pem -passout pass:testpassword 2048
```

The cakey.pem is created, but the output is no different to if I hadn't supplied a -passout.

To test this, I ran the following to self-sign the certificate.  I didn't supply the passphrase, and this still succeeded:

```
openssl req -new -key ./rootca/private/cakey.pem -out ./rootca/csr/ca.csr -subj $subject
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in ./rootca/csr/ca.csr -signkey ./rootca/private/cakey.pem -out ./rootca/cacert.pem
```

To further test this, I signed another certificate, again without the passphrase:

```
openssl genrsa -out ./newkey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key ./newkey.pem -out ./newcsr.csr -subj $subject
openssl ca -batch -config ./rootca/openssl.cnf -in ./newcsr.csr -out ./newcert.pem -days 365
```

All of this worked, so what's wrong with my initial key creation, such that it doesn't require the passphrase to use the key?

Comment: You need to specify an encryption algorithm to go along with the `-passout` option. Otherwise it just silently ignores the `-passout`, probably not the best design.

Comment: Ah, actually. I've just resolved this.  So... I was missing the  -aes256 flag.

Comment: The 'genrsa' is the algorithm.  I haven't moved over to genpkey yet.  Thanks for your response though

Comment: No, aes256 is the encryption algorithm.

Comment: Ah.  great.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the -aes256 flag.
Resolved.  Cheers